# Один модуль не видит пакеты другогомодуля

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

У меня есть два модуля: **StorageHelper** и **RostislavUtil**. Проблема в том, что один модуль не видит пакеты и классы другого! Зависимость на второй модуль есть, второй модуль видит свой класс. При чем сама IDEA предлагает мне добавить модуль в зависимости, а, когда я соглашаюсь, все начинается сначала.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

*pom.xml* модуля **StorageHelper**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>StorageModule</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>StorageModule</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.dugin.rostislav</groupId>
        <artifactId>OSLoaderServer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dugin.rostislav</groupId>
            <artifactId>RostislavUtil</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.47</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.ormlite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ormlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.47</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

*pom.xml* корневого проекта:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dugin.rostislav</groupId>
    <artifactId>OSLoaderServer</artifactId>
    <name>OSLoaderServer</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>RostislavUtil</module>
        <module>StorageModule</module>
        <module>HandlingModule</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

В чем проблема и как это исправить?

---

**UPD_0:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD_1:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File` -> `project structure` -> `Modules` -> Выбираешь модуль StorageModules -> `Dependencies` -> Жмешь зеленый плюсик справа -> `Module dependency` -> Выбираешь модуль `RostislavUtils` -> `Ok` -> `Ok`

Comment: Там была ошибка (ура! я нашел хотя бы зацепку!). Как я понял, не хватает .jar'ника?

Comment: Какого джарника? Можно сделать Module Dependency, а не Library

Comment: А как это сделать, я попытался, но мне написало, что директория с исходниками не может быть в модуле... Я прикрепил скриншот,  чтобы было видно.

Comment: Хотя вынесу это в отдельный вопрос, Вы уже помогли с вопросом выше :)).